# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if'

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

I have written a small bit of code for login page. Code is as follows:

```
if($user == "" || $pass == "") 
{ 
    echo "Please fill in all the information!"; 
} 

//Check to see if the username AND password MATCHES the username AND password in the DB 
else 
{ 
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user' and password = '$pass'") or die("Can not query DB."); 
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
    if ($count == 1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['username']=$user; //Create a session for the user! 
        header ("location: members.php"); 
    } 
    
    else{ 
        echo "Username and Password DO NOT MATCH! TRY AGAIN!"; 
    } 
}
```

I cant run my script, it returns the following error:

PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /var/www/user/login.php on line 38 (second "if")

Comment: It looks valid to me. What is it we can't see? Could have some weird whitespace got there?

Comment: I guess there is something else in the code because the code you provided is less than 38 lines.

Comment: this snippet compiles for me: http://3v4l.org/Mh2GM

Comment: and why not for me? 
http://3v4l.org/6WcTV

Comment: There was whitespace bwefore "$_SESSION['username']=$user;" and after "{" on my questions it's removed by stackoverflow.

Comment: @DavidZIP - Get a better IDE - Removes a lot of hassle by identify these problems

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have weird characters in your script.  When I remove the indentation in the [code you pasted](http://3v4l.org/6WcTV), the syntax error is reported in the next line.

Right before the offending line, there is a "non-breaking space" character (code 160, 0xa0) in the indentation.  This is how lines 36 to 38 look with visible white space:

```
36: \t\t$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);\n
37: \t\xa0\t\n
      ^^^^ Non-breaking Space
38: \t\tif ($count == 1) \n
```

Replace that with regular spaces and your code should run.

Weird, though, that PHP chokes on the next token instead of complaining that there is an invalid character in the source.